# How to implement one generic method for two classes in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, generic-method

I have an interface that has one ordinary method and one generic method. I have implemented ordinary method for two different classes, but do not now how to do that with generic method. Here is my code:

Sphere.java:

```
public class Sphere implements GeometricShape<Sphere> {

    private double radius;

    public Sphere (double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double volume() {
        return (4.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI * radius * radius * radius;
    }

    public void describe() {
        System.out.println("Sphere[radius=" + radius + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public Sphere supersize()
    {
        this.radius*=2;
        return new Sphere(radius);
    }

}
```

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle implements TwoDShape {

    private double width, height;

    public Rectangle (double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double area() 
    {
        return width * height;
    }

    public double perimeter() 
    {
        return 2.0 * (width + height);
    }

    public void describe()
    {
        System.out.println("Rectangle[width=" + width + ", height=" + height + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle supersize() 
    {

        this.width*=2;
        this.height*=2;
        return new Rectangle(width, height);
    }


}
```

TwoDShape.java:

```
public interface TwoDShape extends GeometricShape 
{
    public double  area();

}
```

ThreeDShape.java:

```
public interface ThreeDShape extends GeometricShape<ThreeDShape>
{
    public double volume();
}
```

GeometricShape.java:

```
public interface GeometricShape<T extends GeometricShape<T>>
{
    public void describe();
    public T supersize();

}
```

and finally main class ArrayListExample.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ArrayListExample {



     public static void describe_all( ArrayList<? extends GeometricShape> shapes )

     {
         for(int i=0;i<shapes.size();i++)
         {
            shapes.get(i).describe();

         } 
         System.out.println("Total number of shapes:"+ shapes.size());
     }



     public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("The describe() method:"); 

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Example rectangles");
        ArrayList<Rectangle> rects = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        rects.add(new Rectangle(2.0, 3.0));
        rects.add(new Rectangle(5.0, 5.0));
        describe_all(rects);
        System.out.println();


        ArrayList<Sphere> spheres = new ArrayList<Sphere>();
        spheres.add(new Sphere(10.0));
        spheres.add(new Sphere(50.0));
        spheres.add(new Sphere(0.0));

        System.out.println("Example spheres");
        describe_all(spheres);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The supersize() method:"); 
        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<Rectangle> double_rects = supersize_list(rects);
        describe_all(double_rects);
        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<Sphere> double_spheres = supersize_list(spheres);
        describe_all(double_spheres);

    }


}
```

How can I implement supersize_list method that it takes supersize method from both rectangle and sphere and  outputs like

```
Rectangle[width=4.0, height=6.0]
Rectangle[width=10.0, height=10.0]
Total number of shapes: 2

Sphere[radius=20.0]
Sphere[radius=100.0]
Sphere[radius=0.0]
Total number of shapes: 3
```

Could you help me with this, please? I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I am confused as to why `supersize` will return a new Object, should it not just increase the size of the existing Object?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I agree, it should do either, but not both.

Comment: Yes, i want to increase the size twice in both sphere and rectangle. What are your suggestions ?  I want to write one supersize_list  method that returns both rectangles and spheres with increased size @Scary Wombat @ Luke Lee

Comment: @user_01 That's not what we are confused about.

Comment: Yes, probably I should not return a new object, but I do not  know how I can return new sizes with one supersize_list method. Could you write your approach, please ?

Comment: It appears that `supersize_list()` should be a static method. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class hierarchy looks inconsistent. For example, you have `ThreeDShape extends GeometricShape<ThreeDShape>` and `TwoDShape extends GeometricShape` at the same time, for no obvious reason. It's not fun to write a generic method for these types.

Here's a less-confusing version. (I hope) **Note: I choose not to change the size of the shape itself in supersize method, instead let it return a bigger shape while keeping the original unchanged.**

**1. GeometricShape**

```
/**
 * A geometric shape interface. You can do two things with it.
 * 1. Ask it to describe itself (to stdout);
 * 2. Ask it to return a bigger version of itself (double the size).
 */
public interface GeometricShape<T extends GeometricShape<T>> {
    /**
     * Print a description to STDOUT
     */
    void describe();

    /**
     * Returns a bigger shape.
     * @return Something that's a GeometricShape
     */
    T supersize();
}
```

**2. Shape2D and Rectangle**

```
/**
 * A 2-dimensional shape. 
 * It has area.
 * Its supersize() method should return a Shape2D instance.
 */
public interface Shape2D<T extends Shape2D<T>> extends GeometricShape<T> {

    double area();
}

/**
 * A rectangle.
 */
public final class Rectangle implements Shape2D<Rectangle> {

    private final double width;
    private final double height;

    public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangle{" +
                "width=" + width +
                ", height=" + height +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public void describe() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle supersize() {
        return new Rectangle(width*2, height*2);
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

**3. Shape3D and Sphere**

```
/**
 * A 3-dimensional shape. 
 * It has volume. 
 * Its supersize() method should return a Shape3D instance.
 */
public interface Shape3D<T extends Shape3D<T>> extends GeometricShape<T> {

    double volume();
}

/**
 * A sphere
 */
public final class Sphere implements Shape3D<Sphere> {
    private final double radius;

    public Sphere(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sphere{" +
                "radius=" + radius +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public void describe() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Sphere supersize() {
        return new Sphere(radius*2);
    }

    @Override
    public double volume() {
        return 4*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius, 3)/3;
    }
}
```

**Now the generic method that transforms a list**

```
public static <T extends GeometricShape<T>>
List<T> supersize_list(List<T> list) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T shape : list) {
        result.add(shape.supersize());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Luke Lee for the nice explanation! However, it showed error in both supersize_list method in main such that still did not match to supersize_list for sphere and  rectangle and required cast in front of them in order to correctly run. I could not understand why this error arose

Comment: Are you casting the result to `ArrayList`? Try declare them as `List` instead. `List<Rectangle> double_rect = ...`.

Comment: No, I did not cast result, I casted  ArrayList<Rectangle> double_rects and  ArrayList<Sphere> double_spheres  in order to correctly run. I mean without changing this two, how can I do this in the generic method instead ?

Comment: 'ArrayList<Rectangle> double_rects = supersize_list(rects);
        describe_all(double_rects);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("supersizing a list of spheres");
        ArrayList<Sphere> double_spheres =  supersize_list(spheres);
        describe_all(double_spheres);'    in front of  both supersize_list it showed error

Comment: Then you have to do `ArrayList<Rectangle> double_rects = (ArrayList<Rectangle>)supersize_list(rects); ` to make it work? Change it to `List<Rectangle> double_rects = supersize_list(rects); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128892/discussion-between-user-01-and-luke-lee).

Comment: Yes, in this case describe_all method shows errors. I mean is it possible that, we do not change anything in those ~ ArrayList<Rectangle> double_rects = supersize_list(rects) and ~ArrayList<Sphere> double_spheres = supersize_list(spheres) ~ and fix this in our method ?

Comment: Sorry I cannot join the chat, something blocked by the operator. If you have to , you can change every `List` to `ArrayList` in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to return a new Object.  For `Rectangle` for example

```
@Override
public void supersize() 
{

    this.width*=2;
    this.height*=2;
}
```

is sufficient

Comment: Then it's not going to be generic. But to me it's fine.

Comment: in this case, I should change supersize to an ordinary method in GeometricShape. I want to implement  T supersize()  without changing it

Comment: @LukeLee As `supersize` is acting on the concrete Object's fields, there is no generics involved.  **supersize in Geometric** should also be changed

Comment: I mean how I can implement that generic method without changing it in GeometricShape

Comment: your `GeometricShape` does not need any generics